# edit data gone in shiny data table after input update

Tags: r, shiny, save, edit, dt

I created a data table in Shiny with the first column editable. I can enter texts but they will disappear after I switch input values and then come back. For example, I entered "testing 001" for the **Category** of "Male Premium BladeRazor System" and everything seemed fine (see the picture). However, after I switch my Category to another value and then come back to "Male Premium BladeRazor System", the entered text of "testing 001" would be gone. My code is pretty long, and I cut part of it for your reference. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.
[Example of text edits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7rcY.png)

```
    output$tabofrandom <- DT::renderDataTable(
       if (is.null(names(tab7data$dat))) {
      datatable(tab7data$dat)
     } 
      else {
       datatable(isolate(tab7data$dat),
              editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1,2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9))),
              rownames = FALSE, 
              selection = list(mode = "single", target = "row", selected = previousSelection),
              extensions = c('Buttons'),
              options = list(searching=FALSE, 
                             scrollX=T,
                             scrollY=277,
                             #processing=FALSE,
                             autoWidth = TRUE,
                             displayStart = previousPage,
                             dom = 'Blfrtip',
                             #  pageLength = 5, 
                             lengthChange = FALSE,
                             lengthMenu = list(c(5,10, -1), c("5","10", "All")),
                             buttons = list(c('pageLength','excel'),list(extend = 'colvis')),
                             # buttons = c('excel','colvis'),
                             columnDefs=list(list(targets=c(2,4,5,8), 
                                                  render = JS("function(data){return data.replace(/;/g, 
         '<br>');}")),
                                         ...
                             ))
      )  %>%
       formatStyle(1:10, 'text-align' = 'left') %>%
      formatStyle(1:10, 'vertical-align'='top') 
     } )

   ...
   observeEvent(input[["tabofrandom_cell_edit"]], {
   info <- input[["tabofrandom_cell_edit"]]
   info$col=info$col+1
   previousSelection <<- input$tabofrandom_rows_selected
   previousPage <<- input$tabofrandom_rows_current[1] - 1
   tab7data$dat<-isolate(DT::editData(tab7data$dat,info))
   })
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `server` option of `renderDataTable` to `FALSE` or to use a proxy:

```
proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("tabofrandom")
  
observeEvent(input[["tabofrandom_cell_edit"]], {
  info <- input[["tabofrandom_cell_edit"]]
  ......
  tab7data$dat <- DT::editData(tab7data$dat, info, proxy)
})
```

You don't have to do `info$col + 1` for `editData`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It didn't really work for me. I found a solution online using initComplete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072281/how-to-save-edits-made-in-dt-while-using-selectinput-in-correct-position